# How to order results from a where statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a vote model and a placement model which keeps track of where an employee finished in the vote count at the end of every month.

Vote schema

```
create_table "votes", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "phone_id",    :limit => 8
 t.integer  "employee_id"
 t.integer  "score"
end
```

Placement schema

```
create_table "placements", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "employee_id"
 t.date     "month"
 t.integer  "votes_count", :default => 0
 t.integer  "position"
 t.integer  "total_score", :default => 0
end
```

I can retrieve placements in order of most votes for a particular month like this:

```
business.placements.where(month: month).order('votes_count desc')
```

I want to get the placements in order of average score (and not of most votes).

Average score can be worked out like so:

```
average_score = placement.total_score/placement.votes_count
```

How would I order my where statement by average_score?

Comment: Can't you just add an average score decimal field and have a before save on the placement then order by that field?

Comment: Have you tried "Order BY votes_count DESC" ?

Comment: @Baloo I could but I thought that might be a waste of storage some how. But I think you might be right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
business.placements.where(month: month).order('total_score / votes_count desc')
```

Comment: This response works. Just tested locally. I would recommend you to save that average on the database and order by it instead if you would use that select a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot, but try

```
business.placements.where(month: month).select('placements.*, (placements.total_score/placements.votes_count) AS average_score').order('average_score')
```